# Debug doesn't hit breakpoints in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, breakpoints, hit

I have two solutions which I am running in Visual Studio 2015 , when I am on debug mode in the first one it hits the break point correctly. But with the second one it doesn't do so. I have cleaned the solution , restarted VS checked for another answers in Google and StackOverflow but none of them seems to be working. Do you know what could be the reason for not hitting the break points?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many scenarios like codebehind page defined wrong in aspx page by mistake. If this is not the case close visual studio. There you may see a .suo file for the solution where it doesn't hit breakpoint. Delete that file. Then open vs and open that solution file again.

Let know if this helps